# jQuery - Text is unseen while being animated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create a dynamic meter which fills according to some input. Above the meter there's a text and a divider, which move as the meter changes. This works almost perfect, the only thing that I cant figure out is that the divider and text are unseen while being animated, and sort of pop up upon animation end. How can this be fixed?

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2htksnp/) here;

HTML:

```
<div id="meterContainer" class="meterGeneralStyling">
    <div id="meter" class="meterGeneralStyling"> <span id="reachSpan">ddd</span><span id="testDivider"></span>

    </div>
</div>
<button id="butt">move</button>
```

JS:

```
$("#meter").css("width","15%");   //initial value

function resizeReach(width){
            $("#meter").animate({
                width: ""+width+"%"
            }, 1500);
    }

$("#butt").click(function(){

    resizeReach(Math.floor(Math.random() * 90) + 10 );
});
```

CSS:

```
.meterGeneralStyling{
    position: relative;
}

#row2{
    top: 30px;
}
#meterContainer{
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    height: 10px;
    z-index: -2;
    background-color: #abddff;
    overflow: visible !important;
}
#meter{
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #48B0F7;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;

}

#reachSpan{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 10px;

}

#testDivider{
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    border-left: 3px solid red;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `overflow: visible !important;` to `#meter`

```
#meter{
   height: 10px;
   background-color: #48B0F7;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: So close! :) thanks for the tip. Why does overflow is so important in this case?

Comment: Because `jquery animate` put an `overflow:hidden` by default to the div(text hidden)...why that css rule we bypass that.

Answer (score 0):

You should also have visible for the .meterGeneralStyling

```
.meterGeneralStyling{
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```